# Interpolate given (x,y,z,t) and discrete velocity

Tags: python, algorithm, interpolation

I am doing some interpolation given 5000 points (t,x,y,z) where t is time. Some example points I have would be:

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/976SM.png)

I am using discrete velocity, change(Position)/change(time) for each consecutive point. I want to find a good way to interpolate the velocity at a given time. I know that I can use linear interpolation, but is there a better way to interpolate? I am using Python for this home project.

Comment: scipy's [`interp1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) supports different kinds of interpolation

Comment: Could you elaborate? Since I am (x,y,z) would I use interp2d?

Comment: Are you actually calculating the *velocity* (speed+direction) or only the magnitude of the velocity (speed)? Either way, you could just interpolate each column on its own

Comment: A Kalman filter might be useful, if your objects behave like physical objects with inertia. It combines a model-based expectation for the next position with the next measurement. It's quite math-heavy (lots of matrix operations), but the results can be impressive.